# Terrminal color on OSX

Tags: macos, ubuntu, colors, terminal, ubuntu-16.04

I have an issue which I think IS Ubuntu related.

I have 2 Ubuntu machines - 1 server and 1 desktop (both 16.04). When I access the desktop remotely (ssh) the output from ls -al is in color. However for the server it is just green. This difference tells me that the issue lies with some machine specific configuration not with the terminal.

Any help and/or pointers appreciated.

Comment: are you accessing the server using iTerm or something else.

Comment: If your using bash, you can set Terminal colors in your .bash_profile file.

Comment: @jmh. Thank you for your help.

Comment: i hope that help. I can send you how my terminal is set up for the prompt and color.

Comment: @jmh. No need. I managed to resolve. Thanks again.